# SSRS hidden row become visible with multi group toggle

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have multi group query
I want the only first one to show and plus sign next to it so when user click on the plus sign it opens the lower level group and it has another plus sign

```
+USA
+Australia
```

When click the sign next to USA it should show this

```
-USA
         +Texas
         +California
+Australia
```

when click on the sign next to Texas it should show this

```
-USA
         -Texas
                  +Dallas
                  +Austin
                  +Houston
         +California
+Australia
```

When click on Dallas it shows

```
-USA
         -Texas
                  -Dallas
                           Tom
                  +Austin
                  +Houston
         +California
+Australia
```

I have done the report by making all rows hidden and toggled by the row above

but for some reason the when i do it for CName toggled by C3 it works, now when I make C3 hidden and toggled by C2 for some reason CName shows again!!

I dont know why, any one know why?

Thanks

This is my query

```
select  'USA'as C1,'Texas' as C2,'Dallas'as C3,'Tom' as CName UNION
select  'USA'as C1,'Texas' as C2,'Austin'as C3,'Adam' as CName UNION
select  'USA'as C1,'Texas' as C2,'Huoston'as C3,'Ken' as CName UNION
select  'USA'as C1,'California' as C2,'Los Angeles'as C3,'Dave' as CName UNION
select  'USA'as C1,'California' as C2,'San Fransisco'as C3,'Sam' as CName UNION
select  'USA'as C1,'California' as C2,'Hollywood'as C3,'Sean' as CName UNION
select  'Australia'as C1,'NSW' as C2,'Sydney'as C3,'Richard' as CName UNION
select  'Australia'as C1,'NSW' as C2,'Dubbo'as C3,'Arnold' as CName UNION
select  'Australia'as C1,'VIC' as C2,'Melbourne'as C3,'Mike' as CName UNION
select  'Australia'as C1,'VIC' as C2,'Doncaster'as C3,'Matt' as CName UNION
select  'Australia'as C1,'VIC' as C2,'Craigieburn'as C3,'Kate' as CName UNION
select  'Australia'as C1,'QLD' as C2,'Brisbane'as C3,'Edward
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think the simplest/easiest option is going through the report wizard and create a new tabular report, group by C1, C2, and C3 with CName being the details.[image: Grouping] Make it stepped and enable DrillDown.[image: Drilldown] The final result should function as you wish.[image]

Comment: thats what I did, but the CName still shows when I made C3 toggled by C2.. try it you will understand